# removing single characters from a sentence

Tags: r

I'm string to clean some sentences that contain single characters, for instance:

```
sentence <- c('this is a z test', 'remove this b from here')
```

I want to remove the  `z` and `b` from the sentences to have:

```
c('this is a test', 'remove this from here')
```

I have tried something like this:

```
gsub('"([\\b[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,1}\\b])"', '', sentence)
```

but it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `gsub` with word boundary (`\\b`)

```
gsub("\\s\\b[zb]\\b", "", sentence)
#[1] "this is a test"        "remove this from here"
```

If it is to remove values other than 'a' or 'i', specify `^` within square bracket

```
gsub("\\s\\b[^ai]\\b", "", sentence)
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response, that works. can that regex be updated to remove anything that is not 'a' or 'i'?